# My button is flickering

Tags: java, button, applet, awt

My buttons are flickering and i don't know why. When i click the Formulas button and it sets the NextPage and HomePage button visible, the NextPage button flickers while the HomePage does not. I can click the buttons if I time it right and then LastButton has the same problem with flickering

I checked to see if it was because of the applet being constantly repainted but that does not seem to be the problem. I am honestly really confused about why it would do that since it is not being constantly refreshed.

Here is my code and thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Summative extends Applet
    implements ActionListener
{
    Button Formulas = new Button ("Formulas");
    Button StartQuiz = new Button ("Start Quiz");
    Button NextPage = new Button ("Next Page");
    Button LastPage = new Button ("Last Page");
    Button HomePage = new Button ("Home Page");
    boolean Formulae = false;
    boolean Start = false;
    boolean lesson = false;
    int count = 1;
    int i = 0;
    boolean Home = false;
    URL url;
    Image mathmeme1;
    Image background;
    int level = 0;
    public void init ()
    {
        this.setLayout (null);
        setSize (1280, 800);
        try
        {
            url = getDocumentBase ();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        mathmeme1 = getImage (url, "MathMeme.jpg");
        background = getImage (url, "PIE.jpg");


        setBackground (Color.white);
        Formulas.addActionListener (this);
        StartQuiz.addActionListener (this);
        NextPage.addActionListener (this);
        LastPage.addActionListener (this);
        HomePage.addActionListener (this);
        add (Formulas);
        Formulas.setBounds (590, 200, 100, 40);
        add (StartQuiz);
        StartQuiz.setBounds (590, 300, 100, 40);
        add (NextPage);
        NextPage.setBounds (1180, 760, 100, 40);
        NextPage.setVisible (false);
        add (LastPage);
        LastPage.setBounds (0, 760, 100, 40);
        LastPage.setVisible (false);
        add (HomePage);
        HomePage.setBounds (590, 760, 100, 40);
        HomePage.setVisible (false);


    }


    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor (Color.white);
        g.drawImage (background, 0, 0, this);
        if (Formulae == true)
        {
            g.drawString ("lesson" + count, 100, 100);
            if (count < 4)
                NextPage.setVisible (true);
            if (count > 1)
                LastPage.setVisible (true);
            HomePage.setVisible (true);
            Formulas.setVisible (false);
            StartQuiz.setVisible (false);
        }
        NextPage.setVisible (false);
        LastPage.setVisible (false);
        if (Home == true)
        {
            Formulae = false;
            lesson = false;
            count = 1;
            Formulas.setVisible (true);
            StartQuiz.setVisible (true);
            HomePage.setVisible (false);
        }
        g.fillRect(i, 1, 100, 100);
        g.drawString ("" + i, 100, 400);
        i++;
    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getSource () == Formulas)
        {
            Formulae = true;
            repaint ();
        }
        if (evt.getSource () == StartQuiz)
        {
            Start = true;
            repaint ();
        }
        if (evt.getSource () == NextPage)
        {
            count += 1;
            repaint ();
        }
        if (evt.getSource () == LastPage)
        {
            count -= 1;
            repaint ();
        }
        if (evt.getSource () == HomePage)
        {
            Home = true;
            repaint ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `repaint` function at?

Comment: in actionPerformed?

Comment: Yes, what is the definition for `repaint` that is being called from within `actionPerformed`?

Comment: The way you're using `paint` is NOT how `paint` should be used. You should never change the state of the UI from within the context of a paint method.  Instead, you should be changing the state of the UI from within your `ActionListener`

Comment: Instead, what you really want to be using is a `CardLayout`

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: this is run on ReadytoProgram, not a web browser

Comment: also gmiley i have no idea what that means, could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, let's start with the fact AWT was superseded by Swing over 16 years ago and the Applet API has been officially marked as deprecated for the up and coming release of 1.9, so generally, you're not doing yourself any favours either way. You are of course welcome to do as you please, but I wouldn't hold my breath for a lot of support.  But as I said, you're using the `paint` method incorrectly

Comment: @gmiley `repaint` is a method of `Applet` which causes a paint event to be placed on the event queue, which when processed by the Event Dispatching Thread, will call the applet's `paint` method

Comment: its for school, so i don't really have a choice, otherwise i would be using eclipse

Comment: You can still use Eclipse, it's just an editor. You also need to tell your school it's to join the new millennium :P, maybe point them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)